# ASP.NET Control Choice?

Tags: asp.net, controls

I want an ASP.NET Control possibly free that helps me achieve the following:

The control should be capable of having paging enabled. The trick I have is paging is required on the column level not row. I want to have a capability where I can show x number to columns at times.

*The normal paging for a grid/view is done horizontally on the records. For example if we have 10 records in the bound dataset and paging size is 5 we will have 2 pages. First page having the first 5 records and the second one containing the rest 5.
In my situation the number of rows will always be the same i.e. if there are 10 rows in the retrieved data set then 10 rows will be displayed straight off. But the number of columns can vary. Hence the paging on column level. I am not sure about how to most effectively achieve this. Cells need to have a editable control (Most possibly a textbox)* I am using ASP.NET 4.0.

Comment: Can you explain a little more?  If you just need individual columns to be page-able then you could just make each column be its own `DataGrid` with its own paging and just style them to look like one grid.

Comment: I think what he is asking is to only visibly show some subset of columns at a time. There are complicated ways this can be done, but the simplest is to just handle it via CSS and Markup on the client. You can put it inside a DIV element with it's width set and have scroll bars for the overlflow.

Comment: GridView or DataGrid? It's not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for the reply peps. As you have asked I have added some more text to the question. Sorry for not being much informative in the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure what you mean by... "where i can show x number *to columns at times*", but barring something truly complex not mentioned in your post the asp:GridView control should cover your needs.

It's 'free' in the sense that it comes with Visual Studio.

ed: and per 'David', a DataGrid (or DataGridView) control would also likely suffice.  There are a variety of options you can approach, just seek some online examples, bind the data, tweak your control appearance, and you'll be cooking with gas.  ^^

Answer (score 0):

*Simplest* solution I can think of.

**Markup:**

```
<div id="myExtraWideGrid">
    <asp:GridView>
        <!-- All your configuration options -->
    </asp:GridView>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#myExtraWideGrid
{
    width:400px;
    overflow:scroll;
}
```